# Comparing images - one with coloured dots and one without

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am writing a tool for a game and I am stuck on doing some image comparison.

Basically, I take a snapshot of the minimap, and compare it with a saved image I have of the same area to detect the presence of that part of the map.

However, when in game, various white or yellow dots appear on the minimap in random positions, which can make it hard to compare the similarity of the images.

I've used the template matching feature of OpenCV but I had to set the threshold very low, but this often resulted in false positives.

Is there some way to ignore the variable details, i.e. the dots?

Thanks!

First image is without variation, and second image is snapped in-game. I am looking for a way to compare the images and get some value that indicates high level of similarity.

[image: image without variation]
[image: image with variation]

Comment: Weird, the correlation score should work like a charm. As the backgrounds are identical, you can consider the SAD or SSD similarities, or even count the equal pixels. Make sure that the images are properly registered.

Comment: Not sure why it would be necessary, but I guess you could template match to find the yellow dots and inpaint them before running your existing algorithm.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: inpaint ? What for ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust OP is suggesting that images need a very low threshold to be matched as similar. As the yellow dots are the only difference, my idea was to remove the dots and fill the holes with inpainting which I assume, without having seen OP's code or actual results, would tend to make the images more similar. I'm happy to concede I may be wrong.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I can't understand why OP needs to "set the threshold very low". Despite the dots, the matching score should be excellent.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I agree. OP needs to show code and results for a better analysis.